# The argument type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrap the app in a scrollconfiguration to remove the scrollglow. This always worked but it has been quite a time since i used flutter so i created a new project but it gives this error.

```
ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'testing',
        themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
        darkTheme: darkTheme(),
        theme: lightTheme(),
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        initialRoute: '/',
        builder: (context, child) {
          return ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: RemoveScrollGlow(),
            child: child,
          );
        },
      )
    )
```

The probleme is child: child. I have no idea how to fix this.

```
class RemoveScrollGlow extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(
    BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have updated the dart SDK version and hence null safety is included in your project.

It's pretty simple to solve just go to your **pubspec.yaml** file and under environment variable, you will find the dart SDK range which should be something like this
**sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"**.

Now you just have to change it from 2.12.0 to 2.7.0 which will enable your project to run without null safety and will make your project error-free. So the updated sdk version should look like **sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"**.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: is there way to do it in 2.12.0 i.e default version

Comment: Yes, as Riwen said put '!' at the end of the child or widget name, like ```child: child!```

Answer (score 19):

If you are sure the value will never be null, you can cast it to the non-nullable type, ie. `Widget` explicitly. Or simply add an `!` suffix, like this: `child!`.

Comment: propery syntax is `child: my_widget as Widget`;

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled the null-safety in your project. and your `child` have the type of `Widget?` where as child of `ScrollConfiguration` requires the type `Widget`.

What is the difference between `Widget` and `Widget?`?

`Widget?` indicates that it can have null value whereas the type of `Widget` is non-null.

Read more at https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Yeah i get it that it is something with null safety but i have no idea how to fix this. It doesnt work if i add ? and :

Comment: read the mention link. 
Change Widget? type to Widget of your child.

Comment: I cant change that

Comment: can you add the code or widget tree of your child widget ?

Comment: It can never be null. So why are you using Widget?

Comment: I think i just fixed it. I added this: child ?? Container()

Comment: nothing found helpful but  child ?? Container()