# This is the case for column in my StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

**Flutter**

```
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget ?title;
    Widget ?icon;
    MyCard({Key? key, this.title, this.icon});

    @ override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                title,
                icon
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
}
```

I get the following error:
A value of type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget' because 'Widget?' is nullable and 'Widget' isn't.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Because the type of the`children` in the`column` is `<Widget>[]` not `<Widget?>[]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The argument type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598889/the-argument-type-widget-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-widget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `title` and `icon` can be null at runtime but `Column()` does not allow you to add `Widgets` in `children` that are going to be null.

You can add a null check on your `title` like this `title!` and the same for `icon` to `icon!` or you can give a constant `Widget` to your title and icon when they comes as null at runtime. Something like this

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    title ?? const Offstage(),
    icon ?? const Offstage(),
  ],
),
```